# How to send variable from array of struct objects via segue - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, xcode6

I have a tableview that shows multiple text labels and a single image in each cell from an array of struct objects.  One of the variables within each struct object in the array is a string variable containing the file name of a second image (not originally shown in the cell)

How do I code so when the user clicks on a row in the table, the second image is sent via the segue into an image view in the detail view controller?

TableViewController code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let courseSection = courseData[indexPath.row]

    var tipPic = courseSection.plan
    var courseImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: tipPic)!

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destViewController : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

    destViewController.receivedPic = courseImage
```

DetailViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var bigTipPic: UIImageView!

var receivedPic: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

bigTipPic.image = receivedPic

}
```

Many thanks

Comment: It's the string variable "plan" for the row selected I am trying to convert to a UIImage and send to the image view in the second view controller

Answer (score 0):

Change the prepareForSegue like this:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destViewController : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

    let courseSection = courseData[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row]

    var tipPic = courseSection.plan
    var courseImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: tipPic)!

    destViewController.receivedPic = courseImage
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately build fails.  
'NSIndexPath?' does not have a member named 'row'

Comment: Just add ! to the tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row <--

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to add a bit more information on that.

Comment: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CGC15.DetailViewController 0x7f8eb4111b80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tipPic.'

Comment: Are you sure, you have enough data in courseData array?

Comment: Yes it contains the variable "plan" which is a string variable containing the string name of a gif file.  Have also tried referencing a .jpg file and same issue.  (separate question - are gif file names supported?)

Comment: You need to have the same amount of objects in courseData as you have rows.

Comment: Hmm, then check for segues, and try to add breakpoints, so you'll know where exactly the program crashes.

Comment: Doesn't crash now.  There was an old connection to a deleted image view.  Now the segue works but there is no image!  just a blank controller?

Comment: Okay, do you have your images in Images.xcassets ?, or are you loading them directly from file?

Comment: They are copied into supporting files.  first image shows fine in cells.

Comment: Try loading them like this: var boundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()

let yourImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: boundle.pathForResource("imageName", ofType: "png")!)

Comment: received pic is nil still for some reason.  If I force unwrap received pic it unexpectedly finds nil and crashes

Comment: You sure you wrote the correct image name and type?